# Canonical Rewrite with Folder Redirects (.htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have tried many answers found on this site to help with redirecting on my organization's Web site.

We currently are using the following code to *add* the www prefix to our domain as the preferred address:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Ensure www on all URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This works quite well for the root and subfolders, but if I have a redirect placed below it, I get a 404 as if it is not adding the www prefix.  For example, the following code will not redirect properly for one of the URLs; otherwise it works fine.

URL: www.domain.com/page (works)

URL: domain.com/page (gives 404)

```
Redirect 301 /page /department/features/page/
```

I suspect I need to use a mod rewrite instead of "Redirect 301" for all redirects afterward.  I have tried several variations listed on this site as well as elsewhere, but it yields similar results.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  It feels like this is an extremely simple fix, and I must be overlooking something quite obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must be misinterpreting what's going on, a rewrite define in htaccess will not get a chance to run until after your redirect has already been returned to the client.

Comment: So, you are saying that the order of operations for these elements in the .htaccess file are 1) Redirect lines and 2) mod Rewrite lines, regardless of their placement in the file?

It appears that some confusion on my end is caused by my company's internal network domain controller being named the same as our domain name. Allegedly, for security and functionality reasons, port 80 for that domain cannot be forwarded to the Web server for handling.  It was for a limited time while troubleshooting this issue, but now it is not--hence the erratic results.